# Zip Overwrite Fix

Tags: vbscript

I should probably preface this and say I am very new to Vb Script. I have some experience in C# which feels very similar. I am trying to complete a task for work.

This task will look in a location and find all files older than a certain date. Then the script will take all of those files and zip them into a zip folder based off the month of the zip file. This task will be ran monthly. The original script written (read: pieced together from google) worked fine on small samples. But when applied to folders with over 10K files, it bombed out after about 3000 files and stopped archiving.

I then decided to make the script run weekly to lower the impact. The ideal scenario is run weekly and compile all files into one zip file named for that month. So the script runs the first monday of the may and puts 100 files in the "May" folder. Then on the second monday that script runs again and puts all of the files into the same May zip file. The problem I have, is it overwrites the current files.

Here is my code. Any Suggestions?

```
OriginalDir = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Log_Test\Test"

DoZips(OriginalDir)

Function DoZips(Dir1)

'create empty zip file

a = Split(Dir1,"\",-1)

MyZip = Dir1 & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)-1) & "_" & "archive" & ".zip"     'Naming of the zip file

CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") _
.CreateTextFile(MyZip, True) _
.Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)

'zip content into zip file

on error resume next

Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oFolder = oFS.GetFolder(Dir1)

For Each File In oFolder.Files

    If Right(LCase(file.path),4) <> ".zip" Then

        If File.DateLastModified < Date Then        'Change this number to set the age cutoff

            With CreateObject("Shell.Application")

                .NameSpace(MyZip).CopyHere File.path        'Copy the file to the zip folder

                    wScript.Sleep 4000      'Set wait time between archive and delete to ensure complete file archive

            file.delete     'Delete the file after archive      

            End With

        End If

    End If

Next

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "All Files in " & myZip & " Successfully zipped", 5, "Compression"



set ObjFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ObjLog = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\me\Desktop\Log_Test\log.txt")
objLog.WriteLine nCompressed & " of" & ubound(arFiles) + 1 &_
" Eligible files were compressed and zipped to location " & myZip & " on " & Date

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CreateTextFile call, passes `True` as the **overwrite** parameter, meaning that you create a new, empty zip file every time...

Check if the file exists for the current month first and only create it if it's not already there...

Comment: So something like this: If not objFSO.FolderExists(MyZip) then...create the folder?

Comment: perhaps with objFSO.FileExists though, since a zip file is a file and not a folder?